# Minor version difference in gacutil and environment causing major headaches

Tags: c#, .net, version, c#-2.0, global-assembly-cache

Here's the situation:

I have a DLL compiled in .NET 2 that goes in the global assembly cache.  I have the `myDLL.dll.config` file which reads:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="myDLL" publicKeyToken="c426c33bab532523" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.2.0-1.2.2.22" newVersion="1.2.2.23" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I then use the assembly linker to create the policy file:

```
al /link:myDLL.dll.config /out:policy.1.2.myDLL.dll /keyfile:myDLL.snk
```

But when I try to load the policy file into the global assembly cache using

```
gacutil -i policy.1.2.myDLL.dll
```

I get the error:

```
Failure adding assembly to the cache:  This assembly is built by a 
runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

The .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility version is 2.0.50727.42, but I checked the version on the build environment by creating a new C# .NET 2 console project, and executing the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Environment.Version.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

and my Environment.Version is 2.0.50727.5466.

This is all happening on the same computer, specifically, my dev box.

I can copy myDLL.dll from the \bin\release folder into c:\Windows\assembly folder, no problem.  But trying to either copy-past the policy.1.2.myDLL.dll file from \bin\release to \assembly, or using gacutil fails.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/e76f5c46-e679-4923-bf9d-1f883074eb2e/ ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the .NET 2.x version of al?

Comment: @TimB I'm not sure.  I opened up a new Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt, typed in "al", and got `Assembly Linker version 10.0.30319.1`.  I'm a bit new when it comes to working with dlls in the global assembly cache.

Comment: You should have an al.exe in %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin and another in %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools. They both have the same version number, but the first is for .NET 2.x and the latter is for .NET 4.x. I would specify the full path to make sure you are using the right one.

Comment: @TimB, you solved my problem.  Now I get to go explain to my boss why I wasted half a day working on this *$%! thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that the policy assembly is being compiled for .NET 4.x.

There is an al.exe in %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin and another in %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools. They both have the same version number, but the first is for .NET 2.x and the latter is for .NET 4.x. You should specify the full path to make sure you are using the right one.